# How to format date string with date-fns without timezone transformation?

Tags: format, date-fns

I have really simple date as string as ISO `const mytDate = '2021-10-24T16:00:00.000Z'` and I want to format it like `format(new Date(myDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')` but `new Date()` cause that it convert it to my local timezone and I do not want it. I would like to take this string date and just format it as it is.

Is there a solution ?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I did not have any solution so I prepared custom util for that:

```html
const getRawDate = (rawDate) => {
  if (!isValid(new Date(rawDate))) {
    return null;
  }

  // Split by T separator in order to take date and time
  const [date, time] = rawDate.split('T');
  // return date and time without timezone indication.
  return `${date} ${time.slice(0, -5)}`;
}
```